# Splitting variable length strings into codes (also of variable lengths) in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've been playing around with Excel quite a lot in the last few weeks and I want to make my life easier by having a blanket formula I can apply to my spreadsheet to extract all the codes from within a field.

Ordinarily, I'd just look to see what the codes were separated by and just do MID()s with a FIND() on the column before or "_" but, in this case, **everything** gets separated by underscores, not just the codes, and sometimes the codes are separated by hyphens instead so the naming convention which I've not been made privvy to is causing me quite a bit of trouble on this..

**Example:**

Let's say we have a string like this to work with

```
blahblahblah_n-codeone-codetwo_codethree_blah.blah
```

I would want to be extracting "codeone", "codetwo" and "codethree", like this:

```
+==========================================================================================+
|                   INITIAL STRING                   |   CODE_1   |   CODE_2   |   CODE_3  |  
+==========================================================================================+
|   blahblah_n-codeone-codetwo_codethree_blah.blah   |   codeone  |   codetwo  | codethree |
+==========================================================================================+
```

Several of the codes are of different lengths, ranging from 5 characters to 3 characters and there can be up to four codes per string.  It would be helpful if the columns for codes that can't be found would be left blank.  For example, if there's 2 codes in the string, then columns CODE_3 and CODE_4 would be left empty.

The formula I tried using most recently is below, but it isn't doesn't handle different lengths of codes or even different numbers of codes so it's not really up to the task.

```
UPPER(MID(B4,(FIND(LOWER(D4),B4)+6),5))
```

Screenshot below of spreadsheet:
[image: Example of how I'd like the table to look once codes are extracted]

If anyone could offer some advice and assistance, that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If a fixed limit of returns can be determined before the formula is crafted then a native worksheet formula could be considered. If not, then a User Defined Function (aka UDF) would be more appropriate and possibly be more appropriate in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about determining the number of codes that would be returned as the file names vary quite significantly thoughout the dataset.  Could you offer some guidance on how to go about writing a UDF to do it?

Comment: There is more detail in the Image Names from the picture you provided than what you are describing here. For example in the picture all of the codes appear to be pre-pended with the following sequence: `_n-`. That could be very useful. Is it a general rule? Also from the picture you appear to be ignoring the first and last codes... every time. Is this also a rule?

Comment: Yeah, the only codes I'm interested in stripping are the last three in the top two rows of the image - CODE 3 is missing from the very top one because I was doing some work on the formula and it was obviously not returning anything at that point - should have been returning 2200. The value for CODE 3 for the second image should also be 788, not 080AC. With regards to the n- preceding the codes, this isn't always the case, as you can see with the 080ac in the first two images - the continuity in this data is a nightmare!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the inconsistency of the **Image Names** as stated by the Olly John

> I'm not sure how I would go about determining the number of codes that
>   would be returned as the file names vary quite significantly thoughout
>   the dataset.

Looking at the samples provided it seems that the `_n-` `string` can be used to split the **Image Name** into pieces (up to 4 pieces “Pn”)

**Image Name**:     `exroof_1405_k16_n-350kh-2_n-041cx-080ac_n-2200_4.jgp`

**P1**: `exroof_1405_k16`

**P2**: `_n-350kh-2`

**P3**: `_n-041cx-080ac`

**P4**: `_n-2200_4.jgp`

Then excluding the first two pieces and the last six characters of the last piece we have following two pieces:

**P3**: `_n-041cx-080ac`

**P4**: `_n-2200`

These two pieces contain up to three codes that are separated by the `_n-` or `-` `strings` resulting in:

**Code1**: `041cx`

**Code2**: `080ac`

**Code 3**: `2200`

Based on the above and the irregular results of the naming convention applied to the **Image Name** I propose the following:

Add working columns to hold the strings used to split the code and to see the partial outcome of the split (see fig. below)
[image]
Fig. 1

**Fields: Description**

**Value\Formula**

**s1**: string used to split

```
_n-
```

**INI to exclude**: Initial string to exclude

```
=LEFT($A2,(-1+SEARCH($C2,$A2,1+SEARCH($C2,$A2))+LEN($C2)))
```

**Len**:    Len of end string to exclude

```
6
```

**END to exclude**: End string to exclude

```
=RIGHT($A2,$E2)
```

**Text with codes**: String holding required codes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,$D2,""),$F2,"")
```

**s2**: string used to split

```
-
```

**p1**: Position of strings found

```
1
```

**p2 to p4**: Position of strings found

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($C2,$G2,1+I2)<SEARCH($H2,$G2,1+I2),
SEARCH($C2,$G2,1+I2),
SEARCH($H2,$G2,1+I2)),
1+LEN($G2))
```

**Code 1 to 3**: Codes

```
=UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID($G2,I2,SUM(J2,-I2)),$C2,""),$H2,""))
```

**Insert Statement**: Statements based on codes

```
=IF(EXACT($M2,""),""," insert into TABLE values("&$B2&",'"&$M2&"');")&
IF(EXACT($N2,""),""," insert into TABLE values("&$B2&",'"&$N2&"');")&
IF(EXACT($O2,""),""," insert into TABLE values("&$B2&",'"&$O2&"');")
```

The working columns can be grouped and shown only when needed see fig. 2
 [image] Fig. 2

Comment: I actually found a way to do it using the answer I accepted yesterday, after adjusting it slightly to better fit the codes (turned out the ones I showed were among the simpler ones to break down) but thanks for your answer - I've no doubt I'll be referring to it in future!

Comment: I expected that there were many other patterns for the file names in your data, that's the reason I propose to have the extra columns so you can see the results and adjust the outcome of the formulas with out changing the formulas but adjusting the variables used by the formula to split the records. Good luck with your project...

Comment: Yeah, there's several.  I've started using the method you gave now as some of the other patters we've got to work with are very different and I couldn't figure a way to manipulate what I'd done before to get it to work so thanks even more, you've been a great help :)

Comment: you are welcome, perhaps you want to revise your accepted answer... let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: How would I adjust the formula to pick up codes prefixed by "_a-" as well?  I've tried adding another IFERROR(...) to it but that didn't work so I'm kind of at a loss..  Sorry if these are nooby questions, I've never really done Excel formulae before now and it's rather alien to me...

Comment: This is an example of the code that uses the "_a-" delimiter

exroof_l405_k16_n-350kc-1_n-041cz-080ac_a-win_3.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89790/discussion-between-olly-john-and-eem).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you have given us enough information to give a complete answer as it is not too obvious which are the codes in the demo strings, but here is the approach I would use:

- use two sets of columns: the first set for finding the places the codes start (using FIND), and the second set for actually finding the codes (using MID), this makes the formulae much easier to develop than trying to do everything on one set of formulae.
- use IFERROR to deal with cases where the find function does not find anything

the first three formulae then would be something like

```
C3 - IFERROR(FIND($B3,"n-"),len($B3))  
D3 - IFERROR(FIND($B3,"-",C3+1),len($B3))  
E3 - IFERROR(FIND($B3,"-",D3+1),len($B3))
```

where the syntax of find is FIND(find_text,within_text,start_num) 
note that by using the values of the previous find as the start_num we work through the string.

the second set of formulae will be something like

```
 IF(C3=len($B3),"",MID($B3,C3+2,D3-C3-3))
```

So long as there is a consistent structure to the file names it should be possible to use this approach.

Comment: Apologies, that was my bad as I was posting with a rather flustered mindset! As you can see from the screenshot of the spreadsheet I posted, the codes are like "041CZ", "080AC" and "2200" or "788". When the codes are in the format NUMNUMNUMCHARCHAR, it's fine as they're obviously all the same lengths but I run into issues when they're just the numbers like 2200 and 788 and also what to do to deal with (up to) 4 codes. Any advice and/or solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: The approach I suggested is a generalised one which should be adaptable to work with any string format so long as it is consistent.

Comment: Fab, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Took a little tweaking but it's working great now - thanks!